# Does Notification Center have keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, macos, notifications

Are there any keyboard shortcuts for controlling Notification Center on OS X Mountain Lion? Of particular interest is a shortcut equivalent of the `Click to Tweet` button that appears at the top of Notification Center (when the requisite option is selected in the Notifications settings pane), but if it happens to have other shortcuts (either predefined, or definable in System Preferences - I couldn't see any) those would be useful as well.

Comment: What does "click to tweet" have to do with Notification Center?

Comment: `System Preferences -> Notifications -> Share Button -> Check "Show share button in Notification Center"` causes a button with that label to appear at the top of NC. I agree it's a weird place to put that button, but regardless, I'm not crazy: it's there. :)

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser… I don't have that option in System Preferences. But in the Notifications Center app there is indeed share_twitter.tiff.

Comment: I believe you need to have at least one Twitter account configured under `System Preferences -> Mail, Contacts & Calendars` (another unintuitive location... guess there's no great place to cram Twitter into OS X :P) in order for the option to appear in the Notification settings.

Comment: Wow. That's utterly strange.

Answer (score 9):

There is a configurable keyboard shortcut to open Notification Center:

[image]

Other than that, there seems to be no way to configure any keyboard shortcuts. The closest I could get is discovering that you can set Notification Center as the action for a hot corner. If you wanted to do this when a key is pressed, you can try combining this with AppleScript (like in [this post](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100418152304108)).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I wonder why apple didn't assign a standard shortcut.

Comment: Unnecessary. Almost everyone has a multitouch device, and if you don't like that, you'd know how to set a short cut yourself

Comment: I think that is an unreasonable assumption, @XAleXOwnZX. A fair majority, maybe. "Almost everyone?" perhaps not. As is the automatic expectation of knowing how to set a shortcut, keyboard, hot corner, or otherwise.

Answer (score 9):

The proper answer to this question is "No." But that's not a very satisfying answer. So if you're determined to have keyboard shortcuts for Click to Tweet in Notification Center, this is what you can do:

**Warning: this is a complete and utter hack, but it seems you can (for now; this might break easily) trigger the Tweet button through a very delicate use of UI scripting.**

- Create an Automator service.
- Give it a single action: Run AppleScript
- Here's the script:

  ```
  tell application "System Events"
      tell process "Notification Center"
          click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
          click button 1 of UI element 1 of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of window "window"
          keystroke "Whatever text you want as your default tweet"
      end tell
  end tell
  ```
- Save the service (obviously modify it from my example), assign it a keystroke in System Preferences, and voila: you've got a keyboard shortcut… until Notification Center gets rearranged and button 1 of UI element 1 of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of window "window" is no longer the Tweet button.

If this looks convoluted, that's because it is. If this isn't something you want to use, I don't blame you, and you can fall back on the answer of "no, there aren't keyboard shortcuts."

Comment: Hah! That's a terrifyingly-fragile solution, but I admire your creativity. :)

Answer (score 4):

While it doesn't work for "click to Tweet", there are indeed three keyboard shortcuts that work with Notification Center. They are <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, and <kbd>return</kbd>. Combined with the ability to assign a keyboard shortcut to open Message Center, normal messages can be responded to using the keyboard alone. The Share button and the Mute switch do not seem to respond to these inputs, however.

Comment: I would like to add that CMD + Shift + D sends the tweet after you input some text into the sheet.

Comment: This does not work anymore in 2023. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @ssppjj yeah, same for me, not working.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I do:

- I have a shortcut set to open Notification Centre. This is mapped to F13, as described in other answers.
- I also have the tab key enabled to move keyboard focus between 'all controls':
  [image: Screenshot]

  1. Press F13 to open NC.
  2. Press the tab key twice until 'click to tweet' is highlighted in blue:
     [image: screenshot 2]
  3. Press the spacebar.
  4. Type my tweet (I haven't found a way to add location without clicking).
  5. CMD+Shift+D to send.

Comment: I've since discovered that this can be buggy.

Answer (score 2):

While not related to Notification Center, you can achieve this easily using the official [Twitter client for OS X](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/twitter/id409789998?mt=12). This has a configuration option for "Global New Tweet" which lets you compose a tweet with a key combination without the Twitter app being in the foreground.

[image: Twitter Preferences Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate:

```
display dialog "Tweet?" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
set mytweet to text returned of result

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Notification Center"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
        click button 1 of UI element 1 of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of window "window"
        keystroke mytweet
        repeat 3 times
            keystroke tab using {control down}
        end repeat
        keystroke space
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I don't find the tab using control down has any effect — the final keystroke space just types a literal space.

Comment: In the keyboard section of system preferences, do you have "full control" enabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a trackpad, there is also a new gesture to show/hide the notification center: swipe with two fingers from the right border of the trackpad towards its center.

This setting can be enabled/disabled in Settings -> Trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

Found a great one!

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>, when notification center is open, reveals an additional switch above the Tweet area, to temporarily disable Notification Center:

[image: Temporarily disable notifications?]

Once you click the switch:

[image: Off Position]

**Edit:**
<strike>Anyone else see this documented anywhere?!? Am I the first one to find this?!?</strike>

[@siracusa](https://twitter.com/siracusa) Documented it in his epic Mountain Lion review: http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/os-x-10-8/4/#notification-center