# Compose Message Shortcut

Tags: macos, messages, notifications

Is there a keyboard shortcut to open Notification Center and begin an iMessage as seen below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no" but you can get around that if you try hard.

See this answer, [Does Notification Center have keyboard shortcuts?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57813/does-notification-center-have-keyboard-shortcuts) for one way using AppleScript and Services. It refers to tweeting but the principle is the same for iMessage.

You can also set a keyboard shortcut to open Notification Centre then use `tab` to move to the iMessage button and `space` to open the new message dialog.